# How to add and remove 'table' in a specific part of the HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I add on each click to the button `Add New table....` to add an HTML content between the `START: add here this table` and `END: add here this table`.

At the same time, if I click on the remove button, it should remove this table from the HTML. Unfortunately it doesn't work.

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="row">

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <a class="btn" id="AddNewTable" >Add NEW table...</a>
      </table>

    <!-- START: add here this table -->

      <table>
        <tr>
            <th>This is a new table...</th>
            <th><button class="remove">Remove this table</button></th>
        </tr>
      </table>

    <!-- END: add here this table -->

      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <a class="btn">Different Content</a>
      </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
var html = "";

html += '<table>';
html += '<tr>';
html += '<th>This is a new table...</th>';
html += '<td><button class="remove">Remove this table</button></td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '</table>';

$(function() {
    $('tbody').sortable();

    $('#AddNewTable').click(function(){
        $('tbody').append(html);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });

    $('#getValues').click(function(){
        var values = [];
        $('input[name="name"]').each(function(i, elem){
            values.push($(elem).val());
        });
        alert(values.join(', '));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From what you've posted there's no any `tbody` element on the page. So each time you click `Add NEW table...` it adds the `html` content to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

use `.after()` to append the table after table ID `AddNewTable`

```
$('#AddNewTable').click(function() {
    $('#AddNewTable').after(html);
});
```

and for the `.remove` button change `tr` to `table`

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parents('table').remove();
});
```

Working demo

```js
var html = "";

html += '<table>';
html += '<tr>';
html += '<th>This is a new table...</th>';
html += '<td><button class="remove">Remove this table</button></td>';
html += '</tr>';
html += '</table>';

$(function() {
  //$('tbody').sortable();

  $('#AddNewTable').click(function() {
    $('#AddNewTable').after(html);
    $('.row').sortable({
      items: "table"
    });
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parents('table').remove();
  });

  $('#getValues').click(function() {
    var values = [];
    $('input[name="name"]').each(function(i, elem) {
      values.push($(elem).val());
    });
    alert(values.join(', '));
  });
});
```

```css
table{border: 2px solid #ccc;cursor:move}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">

    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <a class="btn" id="AddNewTable">Add NEW table...</a>
    </table>

    <!-- START: add here this table -->

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>This is a new table...</th>
        <th><button class="remove">Remove this table</button></th>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <!-- END: add here this table -->

    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <a class="btn">Different Content</a>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```